# How can I get the app version of comment at the Google Play?

Tags: android, comments, google-play

I can only get the comment date, but it seems there is no url/api to get the corresponding  version of specific comment.

I've already tried this api:
https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/
It does not contains the version number:

```
"comments": [
    {
      "rating": 5,
      "creationTime": 1269710736815,
      "authorName": "Nate Kidwell",
      "text": "Tremendous application. More examples would be great (as would integrated rubydocs), but awesome all the same.",
      "authorId": "04441815096871118032"
    },
...
```

Any other solution? I just want the version number

Answer (score 0):

As reported in that library website (This is not an official api. I'm not afiliated to google in any way) is not an official API and Google does not provide any official API for the market.
So if that library doesn't provide any API to get the information you need, there is no other quick and simple way to do that.